# A problem on Ito integral

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $W$ be a standard, one-dimensional Brownian motion. Let $T\in(0,+\infty)$. Then
$$\lim_{\beta\to+\infty}\sup_{0\le t\le T}\left|e^{-\beta t}\int_0^te^{\beta s}\mathrm{d}W_s\right|=0\quad\text{a.s.}$$
Could someone give some hints or proofs?